# Property must be initialised even though type is defined in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, types

I am not sure Stack overflow will like this question. I am learning Kotlin and trying to declare a basic variable without any class.

This is the simplest example.

I now understand why the compiler won't accept it, says it must be initialised. But if I put it inside the main function, then it works fine.

I saw this tutorial on W3Schools and it says you dont have to initialise the variable if you declare its type? Well I have and it still is forcing me to initialise it
https://www.w3schools.com/kotlin/kotlin_variables.php

[image]

It's a simple variable in a file no class:

```
/**
 * Number types:
 * This is the most important, and we should be able to go over it quick.
 * We start from the smallest to the biggest
 */

var byteEg: Byte;
```

Even inside a class it doesn't work:

```
class Variables{
    var byteEg: Byte;
}
```

When I try latentinit it gives an exception: 'lateinit' modifier is not allowed on properties of primitive types

Comment: Compiles and works with Kotlin JVM 1.5.31 in the Kotlin Playground. Which version are you using and where? In any IDE?

Comment: I am using it in IntelliJ ultimate. Compiler is 1.8 I think. I have had nightmares with Gradle, so using Maven. I have just realised it works fine inside the main function, but outside it, it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general principle is that **everything must be initialised before it's used**.<sup>*</sup>

(This is in contrast to languages like C, in which uninitialised values hold random data that could be impossible, invalid, or cause an error if used; and languages like Java, which initialise everything to 0/false/null if you don't specify.)

That *can* happen in the declaration itself; and that's often the best place. But it's not the only option.

**Local variables can be declared without an initialiser, as long as the compiler can confirm that they always get set before they're used.** If not, you get a compilation error when you try to use it:

```
fun main() {
    var byteEg: Byte

    println(byteEg) // ← error ‘Variable 'byteEg' must be initialized’
}
```

Similarly, **class properties can be declared without an initialiser, as long as a constructor or `init` block always sets them.**

In your example, you could set `byteEg` in a constructor:

```
class Variables2 {
    var byteEg: Byte

    constructor(b: Byte) {
        byteEg = b
    }
}
```

Or in an `init` block:

```
class Variables {
    var byteEg: Byte

    init {
        byteEg = 1.toByte()
    }
}
```

But it has to be set at *some* point during class initialisation. (The compiler is a little stricter about properties, because of the risk of them being accessed by other threads — which doesn't apply to local variables.)

Note that **this includes `val`s as well as `var`s**, as long as the compiler can confirm that they always get set exactly once before they're used. (Kotlin calls this ‘deferred assignment’; in Java, it's called a ‘blank final’.)

As another answer mentions, there's an exception to this for [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) variables, but those are a bit specialised: they can't hold primitive types such as `Byte`, nor nullable types such as `String?`, and have to be `var` even if the value never changes once set. They also have a small performance overhead (having to check for initialisation at each access) — and of course if you make a coding error you get an `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` at some point during runtime instead of a nice compile-time error. `lateinit` is very useful for a few specific cases, such as dependency injection, but I wouldn't recommend them for anything else.

---

<sup>(* In fact, there are rare corner cases that let you see a property *before* it's been properly initialised, involving constructors calling overridden methods or properties. (In Kotlin/JVM, you get to see Java's 0/false/null; I don't know about other platforms.) This is why it's usually recommended not to call any of a class's non-final methods or properties from its constructors or `init` blocks.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

What W3Schools fails to mention is that it only holds true for variables that are not top level. So inside functions like

```
fun someFunction() {
    var byteEg: Byte
}
```

if you want to do it with top level declarations you can mark it as `lateinit` like

```
lateinit var byteEg: Byte
```

Comment: I have slightly updated my question, please could you advise me as to why the same thing is happening inside a class?

Comment: @theMyth like Ivo says, you can't do it for top-level variables, which is what the one in your Class example is. If it's directly inside the class declaration, no bueno. If it's inside a function, it's ok.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure inside the class also counts as top level, But inside the class lateinit is not allowed for primitive types. So if I wanted to declare a property inside my class like this, no way around initialising it?

Comment: @theMyth I actually wasn't aware myself that primitive types can't be `lateinit`. So I learned something new. More about it here: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/lateinit-primitive-types

Comment: @theMyth for your use case you might want to solve it by making it nullable, like `var byteEg: Byte? = null`